# Increase distance between side-label and shiny widget in shiny dashboard

Tags: r, shiny

How can I increase the distance between label and input in a shiny dashboard?

```
library(shiny)

ui <- shinyUI(
  pageWithSidebar( 
    
    headerPanel("side-by-side"), 
    
    sidebarPanel(
      fluidRow(
        tags$head(
          tags$style(type="text/css", "label.control-label, .selectize-control.single{ display: table-cell; text-align: center; vertical-align: middle; } .form-group { display: table-row;}")
        ),
        column(2),
        column(4,
               selectInput(inputId = "options", label = "some text", 
                           choices = list(a = 0, b = 1))
        )
      )),
    mainPanel(
      fluidRow( 
        h3("bla bla")
      ))
  )
)
server <- shinyServer(function(input, output) { NULL })
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try adding this line before `selectInput` and make sure to add additional bracket after `selectInput` to close `tags$div`.

```
tags$div(id = "div_test", tags$style("#div_test div {margin-left: 20px}")
```

So it will be:

```
column(4,
       tags$div(id = "div_test", tags$style("#div_test div {margin-left: 20px}"),

       selectInput(inputId = "options", label = "some text", 
                   choices = list(a = 0, b = 1))),
)
```

So basically what this does is that it creates an additional `div` just before `selectIput` which we will use to indent to increase spacing between the label and select input.

[image]